# Functional Programming In Scala - reversing lists exercise

Tags: scala, linked-list, functional-programming

While working trough the exercises and concepts of the book: *Functional Programming in Scala* by Paul Chiusano and Rúnar Bjarnason, I stumbled upon the exercise of writing my own function to reverse a list.

The "suggestion" the authors gave to motivate readers to learn more, was to see if we can write such a function using a fold.

My "non-fold" version is the following:

```
def myrev(arr:List[Int]):List[Int] = if (arr.length > 0) { myrev(arr.tail) :+ arr.head } else arr
```

However, can someone give me some pointers on how to at least start the logic to reverse a list via a fold?

I know that:

```
List(1,2,3,4).foldLeft(0)({case(x,y)=>x})
```

gives me the initial "seed" value, which is 0 above, and that:

```
List(1,2,3,4).foldLeft(0)({case(x,y)=>y})
```

gives me 4 which is the last element of the list.

So I would need to supply as function to foldLeft a sort of "identity" function that can give me an element in a certain position and maybe use it to reverse the list somehow, but I feel at a loss.

I didn't fully understood some Haskell code I found online and I want to "struggle" and try to get there on my own only with some pointers, instead of simply blindly copy some solution, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well... one thing you should do is to stop thinking of Scala `List` as `Arrays`. They are quite different. Scala Lists are actually linked-list with a pointer to the head of list. So... append on `List` of length `n` is `O(n)`. Do not do appends on a list.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am not seeking for efficiency here, I am seeking to learn FP and thinking mostly on an abstract level that uses recursion, functions, HOFs, etc... How could I re-write that code above without an append?

Comment: `list.foldLeft(List[Int]())((acc, item) => item :: acc)`

Comment: The first parenthesis are supposed to be provided with initial value of something that you will use to accumulate through your fold. In this case it will be an empty list of Int. Now you second argument is a function which takes the accumulator and an item from list and returns the accumulated result.

Comment: Thanks I understood everything perfectly. I had never thought of using an empty list as initial value for fold, but the function itself to return the accumulated result sounds perfectly logical. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: In case you want to get sum of list using `foldLeft` you will start with accumulator initial value `0` and your function will return the sum of current accumulator value and current item. --> `list.foldLeft(0)((acc, item) => item + acc)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4).foldLeft(List.empty[Int])((result, currentElem) => currentElem :: result)
res2: List[Int] = List(4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of a function that takes a list and inverse it using foldLeft

```
def reverse (l: List[String]) = 
    l.foldLeft(List[String]())( (x: List[String], y: String) => y :: x )
```

Create a list and call the reverse function

```
val l = List("1", "2", "3")
reverse(l)
```

Result

```
res2: List(3, 2, 1): List[String]
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as the accepted answer from 4 years ago?

Comment: well it's up to you to decide ;), but basically it should give the same result, plus some extra comments